# Finding function dependencies

Tags: python, module, namespaces, dependencies

### Context:

I have to work with a suboptimal API to a compute cluster which works as follows:

- `run(func, args)` where `func` is a function and `args` is a list of arguments. `run` sends each arg in `args` along with (a copy of) `func` to a separate worker of the cluster so that it may execute `func(arg)` and report the result. `run(func, args)` then return the list of results aggregated from the workers.

`func` is executed in a clean and hermetic environment on each worker. This means if `func` uses any non-standard library, the worker may not have the library, and the library/module won't be in namespace when `func` gets executed. Right now, those two problems are solved by:

1. Using the API's `attach(file)` function where `file` may be a module or a script. This sends the given `file` over to each worker so the library
2. Adding `import` statements inside `func` so that the namespace is as expected on the worker.

This leads to annoying code like:

```
import lib

# Code agnostic to being executed on a cluster.
def foo(x):
  return lib.method(2)

...

# At this point we want to executed some of our code on the cluster.
def job(x):
  import lib
  return foo(x)
cluster = Cluster()
cluster.attach(lib)
results = cluster.run(job, [1,2,3])
```

Libraries need to be imported twice (and correctly in `job`) and attached manually to the cluster.

### Question:

Simply given a `func`, can I automatically manage library/module for the cluster? More specifically, is there a way I could gather all the modules necessary to the execution of `func`, send them over to the cluster with `attach` and also decorate `func` to import those modules once on the cluster (essentially replicating the namespace that would be available to `func` at execution time)?

Thanks!

Comment: the answer like everything in CS is of coarse its possible ... the real question is how many hours do you want to spend on it ... its going to be ugly and hacky and take probably several months to get a working solution .... but i guess start by taking a  look at the `inspect` module

Comment: also im curious how you determined that the api you are working with is suboptimal ... it sounds to me like it serves a very specific function, and it appears that it works fine to me ...

Comment: Thanks for the `inspect` module, will look into it.

I was hoping for a suggestion from someone that had previous experience packaging functions and executing them in a different environment. I understand the task in itself is _maybe_ possible and might take a lot of time, but like most things in CS there's a trick to make it easier ;)

I said "suboptimal" because to me it seems like determining library dependencies and attaching files could all be done automatically and not be the user's job.